# Explanation behind the calculation of accuracy in deep learning model

Tags: python, deep-learning, accuracy

I am trying to model an image segmentation problem using convolutional neural network. I came across code in Github which I am not able to understand the meaning of following lines of codes for calculation of accuracy -

```
def new_test(loaders,model,criterion,use_cuda):
    for batch_idx, (data,target) in enumerate(loaders):
        output = model(data)
###Accuracy
    _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
    total_train += target.nelement()
    correct_train += predicted.eq(target.data).sum().item()
```

`model(data)` outputs a tensor of shape `B * N * H * W` 
B = Batch Size
N = Number of segmentated classes
H,W = Height,Width of an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
```

On the first line above, it uses `torch.max()` to find all cases in `output.data` along the dimension - 1(i.e along each row). In addition, `torch.max()` returns `(values, indices)`, so only the indices are stored in a variable called `predicted` while the values are not stored.

```
total_train += target.nelement()
```

The second line above just tracks the total size of the train set into a variable called `total_train` based on the number of elements in `target`

```
correct_train += predicted.eq(target.data).sum().item()
```

The third line above takes the `predicted` variable, which contains all indices of when the output is greater than 1, checks it against `target.data`, and sums up all items that are equal. In other words, it is counting how many of the predicted values are equal to the target data.

Comment: Also, I think there is a simple edit in `torch.max(output.data,1)`. `1` is the dimension across which the maximum value has to be found